# Подскажите как реализовать нестандартную рамку

Tags: css, css3, border

Подскажите как элегантно решить такую задачу с рамкой на css[image: Пример]

Comment: псевдоэлементами или градиентом

Answer (score 2):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #acd,#cda);
}
.block{
  width:300px;
  margin:20px auto;
  position:relative;
  border-left:4px solid red;
  border-right:4px solid red;
}
.inner{
  height:150px;
  padding:10px;
}
.block:before,
.block:after,
.inner:before,
.inner:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:absolute;
  height:4px;
  background-color:red;
}
.block:before{
  top:0;
  left:-2px;
  width:calc(60% - 30px);
}
.block:after{
  top:0;
  right:-2px;
  width:calc(40% - 30px);
}
.inner:before{
  bottom:0;
  left:-2px;
  width:calc(40% - 30px);
}
.inner:after{
  bottom:0;
  right:-2px;
  width:calc(60% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался) Решение с svg))

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/290660/pexels-photo-290660.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350') no-repeat center /cover;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.some-block {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.border {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  stroke-dasharray: 150% 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-block">
  <svg class="border">
<rect></rect>
  </svg>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #acd;
}    
.block{
  background: #acd;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.block:before, .block:after{
  content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #acd;

}
.block:before{
    top: -3px;
    right: 10%;
}
.block:after{
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Здесь ваш текст
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если фон будет не одноцветный? Нет закруглённых краёв на разрывах.

Comment: C фоном проблем не вижу, в вот с закругленные края что то проглазел, просто сижу далеко от монитора, их реально не видно, но тоже все решаемо псевдоэлементами, это я просто набросок сделал каким образом это делается, у вас неплохой вариант, только calc не очень совместимая штука, а так все супер)